# Ngrx selector with .map return error cannot read property

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-selectors

Hello i created this ngrx selector

*Path: src\app\store\navigation\navigation.selectors.ts*

```
export const getNavigationState = createFeatureSelector<NavigationState>('navigation');

const getNavigation = createSelector(
  getNavigationState,
  (state) => {
    return state.entities;
  }
)

/**
 * Get Arrays Of all Categories and submenu
 */
export const getFullMenu = createSelector(
  getNavigation,
  (state) => {
    return state.menu
  }
)

/**
 * Get Arrays Of all Categories and submenu
 */
 export const fullMenuCat = createSelector(
  getFullMenu,
  (categories) => {
    categories.map((category) => {
      return {title: category.title, url: category.url}
    })
  }
)
```

I don't know why, but when i call my observable in my component i have this issue:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**

This is my data from data.json

*Path: src\datas\subnav.json*

```
[
  {
    "id": "angular",
    "title": "Angular stuff",
    "url": "/angular",
    "links":  [
      {
        "name": "Components",
        "url": "#"
      },
      {
        "name": "Directives",
        "url": "#"
      },
      {
        "name": "Services",
        "url": "#"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pipe",
        "url": "#"
      },
      {
        "name": "Other",
        "url": "#"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Those datas are used by ngrx effects

*Path: src\app\store\navigation\navigation.effects.ts*

```
  read$ = createEffect(() => this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.Types.READ),
    switchMap(() =>  {
      return this.navigationService.getCategories().pipe(
        map(data => {
          return new fromActions.ReadSuccess(data);
        })
      )
    })
  ))
```

And finally this is the Navigation interface

*Path: src\app\store\navigation\navigation.models.ts*

```
import { Category } from "@app/models/backend";

export interface Navigation {
  isNavOpen: boolean,
  currentCategory: string,
  menu: Array<Category>,
  lastUrlVisited: string
}
```

and the Category interface

*Path: src\app\models\backend\categorie\index.ts*

```
export interface Category {
  id: string,
  title: string,
  url: string,
  links: Array<Link>
}

export interface Link {
  name: string,
  url: string,
}
```

this is the ts file of my component

*Path: src\app\components\header\header.component.ts*

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
/**State */
import * as fromRoot from '@app/store';
import * as fromNavigation from '@app/store/navigation';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {


  fullMenuCat$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,

  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromNavigation.Read )
    this.fullMenuCat$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromNavigation.fullMenuCat));
  }

}
```

and the fullMenuCat$ observable call in my html

*Path: src\app\components\header\header.component.html*

```
<nav *ngIf="fullMenuCat$ | async  as fullMenuCat">
  <ol class="header__categories__nav">
    <li #link *ngFor="let menuCat of fullMenuCat" class="header__categories__navitem" (mouseover)="moveMarker($event)" (mouseout)="resetMarkerPos()" routerLinkActive="header__categories__navitem-active" >
      <a class="categories-a" routerLink="{{menuCat.url}}">{{menuCat.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

I'm on this problem since 3 days and I don't know what I need to do.
For more clarity here is a repo with my project:
https://github.com/orphen92/angular-demo.git

You can run the projet with "npm run start command"

And a live url
https://orphen92.github.io/angular-demo/angular

I try to create the most scallable architecture, so my code is explosed in many parts and i can't link all the code here (always for clarity).

I hope you can help me

Comment: Hello. With a quick look at your code, I see that you initialize your Store with `StoreModule.forRoot()` but you reference your selectors with `createFeatureSelector()` that takes a name to be used in a `StoreModule.forFeature()` method. I would try to align these 2 : wether you create a feature or not. I would get rid of this feature selector and go with the global store instead.

Comment: Here are some additional informations : https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/ngrx-store-understanding-state-selectors

Comment: Hello thanks for you message.
My other selectors works great, why do you think my selector reference can be a problem just for the fullMenuCat selector?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to give your store an initial state for that `categories`. Or use optional chaining combine with nullish coalescing to give your selector a default value if `categories` is empty, like this:

```
export const fullMenuCat = createSelector(
  getFullMenu,
  (categories) => {
    return categories?.map((category) => {
      return {title: category.title, url: category.url}
    }) ?? [];
  }
)
```

Since you're performing data fetching, `categories` is always going to be empty the first time your selector trying to read it, this is why you should always give your state some initial values

Comment: Hi thank you for this answer. The ? operator help me for resolve the error.
Now  i can see the result of the .map when i console it inside the ts file. But when i call my observable in my template i got no data in the html (call it with fullMenuCat$ | async). Do you know why?

Comment: Ok, so, the `createFeatureSelector()` works just fine, even with a `forRoot()` method, my bad. But the answer from @Nam seem to work just fine (don't forget the `?? []`. But by the way, why do you need another selector when you already have the list with the previous one `getFullMenu` ? Cheers

Comment: my list return full categories  on the top and the submenu of each category on the burger menu.
I try to make a selector for give me just the data i need for the main menu (on the top) and it's also for learning ^^.
The solution of @nam works great but i can't retrieve the data in the html :(.

Comment: Here's a very good tool that I use to debug these kind of problems https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en. The tool record all the actions as well as the new state of the store upon receiving that action which is perfect for identifying where did things start going wrong. But I suspect that in your case it's probably just a syntax error here `this.store.dispatch(new fromNavigation.Read )` => `this.store.dispatch(new fromNavigation.Read())`